# WebSocket Server Application with an extensible (multi layered) architecture

Tags: node.js, websocket, rxjs

Now that I have a back-end server which accepts websocket connections, I need to implement an extensible & testable architecture.

What [https://github.com/websockets/ws] ws provides me is a simple websocket server than listens to new messages. If I go on implementing 50+ different types of messages within the same switch statement, it rapidly goes out of control.

I would like to have some recommendations/ideas on how I can divide and conquer this flow of messages in a more architectural way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve you problem is to use a framework combined with routing module. This will make managing your message managing code readable without extra effort.

A good example of such a combination is express with [express-ws module](https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws). Express-ws is a Syntactic sugar build on top of ws module that among other things allows you to use router middleware to manage your messages.

```
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

const router = express.Router();

router.ws('/echo', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    ws.send(msg);
  });
});

app.use("/ws-stuff", router);
```

Also you can move the message handling logic to "controllers" like this:

```
ws.on('message', function(msg) {
   MessageController.handler(msg);
});
```

The next step would be breaking your routes on separate files depending on business domains to not have one huge file with all the routing

Comment: As far as I understand, the routing pattern is for having multiple different entry points (ws addresses). My problem is having a clear architecture for a single point of entry (ws address) but having 100+ of different kind of messages

Your second approach is more like what  I am looking for. However how this handler will reach to ws object? Should I pass it as a parameter? If so, what if within the controller, I need the websocket server object? So, should I pass the server also ? (to reach out other clients within the controller)